# insert a single row for two or more similar rows

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
BOARDING_PT          DESTINATION          DISTANCE PRICE
-------------------- -------------------- -------- -----
PUNE                 MUMBAI                    400  2000 
PUNE                 HYDERABAD                 800  5000 
MUMBAI               PUNE                      410  2100 
PUNE                 BANGALORE                 900  4500 
HYDERABAD            PUNE                      800  5000 
BANGALORE            PUNE                     9000  4700 
--------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I insert a single row for Mumbai-Pune and Pune-Mumbai and likewise for other such pairs.

Comment: Why is `price` different for `A-B` and `B-A`

Comment: Please post some sample data and the data you need to get as a result. Also, please post what you tried so far

Comment: How would an insert look like. I understand how you look for them but what information do you need inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

INSERT INTO Table(Boarding_Pt,Destination,Distance,price) 
SELECT Destination,Boarding_Pt,Distance,Price FROM Table